# Accessing Exchange server 2013 with PHP

Tags: php, exchange-server-2013

I need to download attachements from an email account on a MS Exchange server 2013.

I found this [PHP Exchange Web Services](https://github.com/jamesiarmes/php-ews) howver before starting to fiddle with it, I would like to know if someone succesfully had made it work with the 2013 version of Exchange (On GitHub it says it's for 2007 and 2010)

Comment: A quick look at the project's issue log gave me [this one](https://github.com/jamesiarmes/php-ews/issues/270) which is about Exchange 2013. The ticket reports that it was working with 2013 but then got an error after an upgrade, but was closed after it turned out to be a server config problem. So from that perspective, it sounds like your question already has an answer.

Comment: You might also consider looking through the forked versions of the project, as some of them seem to have been worked on a lot more recently than the main project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can confirm that PHP Exchange Web Services works well with MS Exchange server 2013 without doing any changes to the classes at all. I'm able for example to list emails, download attachments, move emails to other folders.